# Spring not Initializing

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I am downgrading a small app from Tomcat/Java 8 to Tomcat/Java 7. I had to downgrade Spring from version 5.x to 4.x for this reason. In spite of I am working hard to put stuff running again, Spring context is not starting.

Config:

- hibernate-entitymanager 5.2.15
- mysql-connector-java 6.0.6
- javax.servlet-api 4.0.0
- jstl 1.2
- jta 1.1
- spring-data-jpa 2.0.2
- commons-codec 1.11
- gson 2.8.2
- commons-dbcp2 2.2.0
- validation-api 2.0.1
- spring-core 4.1.4
- spring-context 4.1.4
- spring-context-support 4.1.4
- spring-web 4.1.4
- spring-jdbc 4.1.4
- spring-orm 4.1.4
- spring-webmvc 4.1.4
- javax-servlet.jsp-api 2.3.1

Issue:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath


package com.mycompany.myapp.conf;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class ApplicationInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(SpringConfiguration.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");        
    }

}


package com.mycompany.myapp.conf;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mycompany.myapp")
public class SpringConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    //@Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry
              .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
              .addResourceLocations("/public", "/resources/")
              .setCachePeriod(31556926); 
        }

}
```

Comment: What is the exception during Spring initialization?

Comment: @KarolDowbecki, actually, there's no exception, just information as exposed above. Nonetheless, these classes (initializer and configuration) are not executed in runtime (I am testing through debug). This approach is not supposed to demand web.xml configuration, so, I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a matter of knowledge building:

I discovered that Spring was not recognizing the current directory structure (which was apparently suitable for Java/Tomcat 8 and newer versions of Spring).

Then, I created a new project with the regular Maven directory structure and after that Spring started to view Initializer and Configuration classes.